# iPhone Add View using another View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a tabbar application with individual views.

So I have three views:

MainWindow.xib (tab click) Favorites.xib (button click) AddFavorites.xib

How would I get the Button click to work on the favorites?

Here is my current code and it always crashes.

```
#import "FavoritesView.h"
#import "FavoritesAddView.h"

@implementation FavoritesView

@synthesize favAddView;

-(IBAction) addButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.favAddView == nil)
    {
        FavoritesAddView *fView = [[FavoritesAddView alloc]initWithNibName:@"Favorites" bundle:nil];

        self.favAddView = fView;

        [fView release];
    }

    [super.view addSubview:favAddView.view];
}
```

It gives me an error at the line: [super.view addSubview:favAddView.view];

Error: Program received "SIGABRT"

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: It is supposed to show another view ontop of the current tabbar application view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the last line should be `[self.view.superview addSubview:favAddView.view]`.

Comment: What he said, but I think it's
[self.view addSubview:favAddView.view]
(not superview)

Comment: Neither worked it's still saying "PROGRAM RECEIVED Sigabrt" at that self.view.superview addSubview:favAddView.view] line.

Comment: When does it crash? On the click of the button?

Comment: On the line [super.view addSubview:favAddView.view];

Comment: its either going to be [self.view addSubview:blah] or [self.superview addSubview:blah]